# C: Why won't S_ISDIR recognize a directory?

Tags: c, permissions

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "sys/stat.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
     struct stat s;
     lstat("../", &s);
     if(S_ISDIR(s.st_mode) == 0){
          printf("yes\n");
     }else{
          printf("no\n");
     }
}
```

Result: "no"

When I run different variations of this code (e.g. with S_ISREG) I get the opposite of what I expect every time. So for S_ISREG with "../" I get "yes". I have been messing with this kind of stuff for a while (file permissions, directory creation, etc.) so I don't know if I screwed something up or what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That should be an answer.

Comment: What do you mean? As in this should work or it's currently giving me a correct answer?

Comment: @user2784872: I had commented before posting an answer, R was referring to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `S_ISDIR` incorrectly. That will evaluate to *true* if you have a directory, you're testing for zero, which is *false*.

Replace that with:

```
 if(S_ISDIR(s.st_mode)){
      printf("yes\n");
 }else{
      printf("no\n");
 }
```

Same for the other macros like `S_ISREG`.

The standard reference for these macros is POSIX, which says this in [`sys/stat.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html):

> The following macros shall be provided to test whether a file is of the specified type. The value m supplied to the macros is the value of st_mode from a stat structure. **The macro shall evaluate to a non-zero value if the test is true**; 0 if the test is false.
>
> [...]
> `S_ISDIR(m)`
>  Test for a directory.
> [...]

Comment: I'm not saying I don't believe you but it was working before. Also the man pages and also [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) say that zero is returned if true.

Comment: Where in that page does it say it returns 0? Added the official standard reference in case you still have doubts.

Comment: Wow. My bad. I guessed I attributed the return value to the macros...like an idiot. Thanks so much.